# Ability of "programable background"? (OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa

is it possible to "program the background"? So like a program, that acts as the background but can handle user input? Couldn't find anything on the web, but maybe I just hit in the wrong keywords.

Any ideas or remarks?

Thanks, zcei

(P.S.: asked that on apple stackexchange before, but was ways too offtopic. Don't know where to ask.)

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Could you elaborate on what you really want your app to do?

Comment: In the end the app should have different behaviours. Like in box86rowh answer, the desktop should be "active", but some other as a webpage would be nice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090927121820123

You are looking for something like active desktop on windows. Above is a quick link on how to display a web page as your desktop.  You can setup the web page as you want.

Comment: Does it stay visible when you swipe away the windows? Like on windows minifying everything (bottom right)

Comment: Not sure, you could try it and see.  Or email their support and ask.

Comment: Since Fluid is an application (a web browser), or rather an application (site-specific browser) generator, that means that a custom application could likewise display content at the desktop level.